# How to add webp images as background image of a div with fallback to Jpeg

Tags: typo3, webp

I want to add a background image to a div in webp format with fallback to jpg.

If it is img tag, we can call it as:

```
 <picture>
    <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="image.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</picture>
```

And what can we do in case of `<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('images/image.jpeg')">`

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You cannot have image variants with `background-image:`. The last reason for background-image was in my opinion the necessity to support IE11 which did not allow `object-fit:` on `<img>`. 
If you need to use background-image here, you can use a webserver rule that delivers .webp (under the same URL) if the browser reports that in its `Accept` header. Here is an example for such a rule: https://github.com/plan2net/webp#webserver-example-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Here is a my solution...
You load the image with a hidden picture element and fetch with js the loaded image (with fallback to jpg or png). Finally you set the loaded image with jquery as the background of the parent div.
Maybe there is a better solution in the field.

```js
function makeBgImage( img ){
    let srcImage;
    if ( typeof img.currentSrc === "undefined" ){
        //Old browser
        srcImage = img.src;
    }else{
        //Modern browser
        srcImage = img.currentSrc;
    }
    let ref = $(img).parents('div:first');
    ref.css('background', 'url(' + srcImage + ')');
    if( ref.hasClass('contain') ){
        ref.css('background-size', 'contain');
    }else{
        ref.css('background-size', 'cover');
    }
    ref.css('background-position', 'center');
    ref.css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
}
```

```css
.hidden{display: none;}
.img-container{
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 62.5%; /* 8:5 Aspect Ratio */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container">
  <picture class="hidden">
    <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img onload="makeBgImage(this)" alt="Image" src="image.png">
  </picture>
</div>
```